# LogIn HQL ¿Se puede comparar un objeto con dos variables?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

El objetivo es hacer un LogIn a través de un HQL, actualmente estoy en este punto del código:

```
    public boolean LogIn(String nickname, String password){
        boolean inAnswer = false;

            try{
                inAnswer = true;
                this.session = Hibernate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
                Query login = session.createQuery ("From Usuario usser  "
                            + "where usser.Nickname ='"+nickname+"' & usser.Password ='"+password+"'");

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return inAnswer;
    }
```

Mi pregunta es ¿Puedo implementar un if/switch dentro de ese try que haga una comparación de las variables nickname y password con el objeto login?
Algo como:

```
        if(login.equals(String nickname, String password))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la variable `Query login` que estás utilizando (dependerá de donde la importes) te permite recuperar los valores, podrás hacer lo que pides.

Por otro lado siempre se puede programar dentro de los `try{} catch(){}` además que te permite encapsular/controlar los errores que puedan salir durante la ejecución del código.

```
try{

   //Recuperar texto, desde un txt puede dar excepción IOException
   File f = new File( "C:\\texto.txt" ); 
   BufferedReader entrada; 
   entrada = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( f ) ); 

}catch(IOException ioe){
    ioe.printStackTrace();//Te dará información respecto al error
}
```

Aquí la respuesta a tu pregunta:

```
public boolean LogIn(String nickname, String password){
    boolean inAnswer = false;

        try{
            inAnswer = true;
            this.session = Hibernate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            Query login = session.createQuery ("From Usuario usser  "
                        + "where usser.Nickname ='"+nickname+"' & usser.Password ='"+password+"'");
            //recuperas la informacion de Query login con los metodos que correspondan
            if(login.getUsserNickname().equals(nickname) &&  
               login.getUsserPassword().equals(password){
               //hacer la logica interna que quieras hacer por ejemplo:
               inAnswer = true;
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return inAnswer;
}
```